# 507 rims on a narrow frame

Tags: tire, wheels, bmx

I bought my son a powerlite Jr cruiser. He would like to but a bigger tire on it. It currently has 520mm 24" wheels with 1" tires. Question is how wide is a 24" 507 bmx rim? I can't find specs anywhere. His current rims are 11/16" wide and I think it's possible to fit a 1.75 or 1.50 tire.

Comment: According to [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html), a 507 rim may carry tires between 1.5 and 2.125 inches wide.  This is not to say, though, that a given 507 rim will be ideal for that full range of widths.

Comment: You may also want to take a closer look at tire clearance.  If there is only 1.5 inches of clearance, switching to a rim size that gives you a tire range that starts at 1.5 will reduce the number of tires you can select for the wheelset.

Comment: The issue would be less with the rim capacity, more with clearance between tire and frame. Most BMX minis are designed for 1.5" tire maximums, and, as your son is, are typically run with 1" or 1.25". A larger tire may rub the frame, especially under the frame and wheel flex induced by a hard ride.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger problem here isn't the width of the rim, it's the sizes of tires made in that ISO.  As mentioned in the comments, frame width is another restricting factor.  Junior Cruisers are made for junior riders.  If he's outgrowing it, it may be time to switch up to standard Cruiser or Pro 20" class.  To answer your question, 507 ISO rims are usually between 19 and 24mm wide.  They will run tires from 24x1.25 up to 2.25 and a little bigger for the larger side of the range.  One other consideration is brake position.  Make sure you can get brakes that will reach the(farther) rim position.